# OO Design pattern for shopping cart

Tags: java, design-patterns, database-design, object-oriented-analysis

I am trying to learn oo design pattern and developing shopping cart application where different cart items will have different types. Each type is will have some additional attributes.

Option 1: Is it good to create a separate class with every cart item with their own attributes and common attributes in base class. In this option, I will have to create multiple classes and corresponding table hierarchy in the database.

Option 2: Create single cart item with type attribute which will identify the type of the attribute. Irrelevant attributes for the particular cart item will be null in this case.

I know this is very basic question but I want to know about how people follow best practices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Strategy for this, for example:

```
public interface CartItem{
  String getName();

  BigDecimal getPrice();
}
```

Only work with this interface in your shopping cart. This way, if you want a new cart item, just let it implement this interface, and it will work :)

By using an interface, you still have full freedom in how you design your actual cart items (either having 1 class, or multiple classes)

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you do NOT want to write new code when your application has to handle new things for people to buy.  Therefore, a new class when there are new items to buy is a poor design.

Comment: It is not about new items, It is about new item type. Obviously new item type will have new functionality.

Comment: Still, even a small retail operation is liable to have, and to change, its items more often than you want to write new classes.  Yes, of course it is a new item type, but if your requirements include having these items have new functionality, that's a tough system to program.  I'd evaluate what possible new functionality there is liable to be before I decide it has to be that way.

Comment: I got your point. So can I say that if it has lot of new functionality, it would be good to have new class?

Comment: It is hard to imagine a case where I would make a new class because of "additional functionality" for an item in a shopping cart.  To the shopper, this is an item that they have decided to purchase.  It has pricing, photos, descriptions, SKU number(s), vendors, shipping weight and times, availability, etc., etc.  That's how the shopper views an item in the cart.  It doesn't change much from sweaters to used cars, from cantelope to cameras, whatever.  Many people new to OO programming try too hard to fit their problem into something for which they can use inheritance; try not to do that.

Comment: I agree to your points and I am also doing the same thing. But when I read design patterns and specially open closed principle, it states that our design should be  open for extension and closed for modification. 

If I come across scenario where 
if (itemtype == type1) {
 // do something
}
if (itemtype == type2) {
 // do something else
}

Now if in future it comes type3. I have to change this code every time. Instead, if I do inheritance, then I do not need to change this code. I will call particular type's method. What say?

Comment: Avoiding that kind of code is a good idea, but in a software system of any size, it is a poor way to decide on class design.  Start with the essential requirements of your system and think about the types of objects that it will have.  Think about what things in the system are liable to change often, and how to minimize changes in code due to requirements you can guess will change.  Create classes to model those requirements and changes.  Then think about essential coding sections; if you find that questionable coding practices like the one you mention are required, then rethink the design.

Answer (score 1):

I was asked a similar question in an interview. The exact requirement was

Design a shopping cart with products and coupons and calculate the net price after applying coupons on products. Coupons can be of different types with certain conditions. I tried to use abstraction among Coupon/Discount processing, Cart and Product implementations classes.

1. N% off that is 10% off for all the individual.
2. D% off on next item of Type T.
3. D% off on next item of Type T.

Sequentially apply all the coupons on the cart and get the Total amount.

I could come up with following solution. I used CoR pattern.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

interface Cart {
    List<CartItem> getItems();
    // void setItems(Set<CartItem> cartItems);
}
class ShoppingCart implements Cart {
    private List<CartItem> items = new ArrayList<>();
    boolean addItem(CartItem item) {
        return items.add(item);
    }
    boolean removeItem(CartItem item) {
        items.remove(item);
        return true;
    }
    public List<CartItem> getItems() {
        return items;
    }

    public double totalCartValue() {
        double total = 0;
        for (CartItem item : items) {
            total += item.getPrice();
        }
        return total;
    }
}
interface CartItem  {
    public String getName();
    public double getPrice();
    public void setPrice(double price);
}
abstract class Product implements CartItem {
    String name;
    double price;
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public double getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public void setPrice(double price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
class Card extends Product {
    public Card(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
class Tshirt extends Product {
    public Tshirt(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
class BackPack extends Product {
    public BackPack(String name, double price) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
interface Coupon {
    void apply(Cart cart);
    void setSuccessor(Coupon successor);
}
class CouponAll implements Coupon {
    private static final float DISCOUNT = 0.25f;
    Coupon successor;
    public void setSuccessor(Coupon successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }
    public void apply(Cart cart) {
        for (CartItem item : cart.getItems()) {
            item.setPrice(item.getPrice() - item.getPrice() * DISCOUNT);
        }
        if (successor != null) {
            successor.apply(cart);
        }
    }
}
class CouponNext implements Coupon {
    private static final float DISCOUNT = 0.10f;
    private int discountItemIndex;
    Coupon successor;
    CouponNext(int discountItemIndex)   {
        this.discountItemIndex = discountItemIndex;
    }
    public void setSuccessor(Coupon successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }
    public void apply(Cart cart) {
        if(discountItemIndex < cart.getItems().size())  {
            CartItem cartItem = cart.getItems().get(discountItemIndex);
            cartItem.setPrice(cartItem.getPrice() - cartItem.getPrice() * DISCOUNT);
        }
        if (successor != null) {
            successor.apply(cart);
        }
    }
}
class CouponNextBackPack implements Coupon {
    private static final float DISCOUNT = 0.15f;
    private int discountItemStartIndex;
    Coupon successor;
    Class<?> productType;
    CouponNextBackPack(int discountItemStartIndex ,Class<?> productType)    {
        this.discountItemStartIndex = discountItemStartIndex;
        this.productType = productType;
    }
    public void setSuccessor(Coupon successor) {
        this.successor = successor;
    }
    public void apply(Cart cart) {
        if (discountItemStartIndex < cart.getItems().size()) {
            for (int i = discountItemStartIndex; i <  cart.getItems().size(); ++i) {
                CartItem cartItem = cart.getItems().get(i);
                if(productType.isInstance(cartItem))    {
                    cartItem.setPrice(cartItem.getPrice() - cartItem.getPrice() * DISCOUNT);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (successor != null) {
            successor.apply(cart);
        }
    }
}
public class DriverClassCoR {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Product card1 = new Card("Card", 12.99);
        Product card2 = new Card("Card", 12.99);
        Product card3 = new Card("Card", 12.99);
        Product tshirt1 = new Tshirt("Tshirt", 24.99);
        Product tshirt2 = new Tshirt("Tshirt", 24.99);
        Product backPack1 = new BackPack("BackPack", 34.99);
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart();
        cart.addItem(card1);        cart.addItem(card2);        cart.addItem(card3);
        Coupon couponAll = new CouponAll();
        cart.addItem(tshirt1);
        Coupon couponNext = new CouponNext(cart.getItems().size());
        couponAll.setSuccessor(couponNext);
        Coupon couponNextBackPack =null;
        couponNextBackPack = new CouponNextBackPack(cart.getItems().size(),  BackPack.class);
        couponNext.setSuccessor(couponNextBackPack);
        cart.addItem(tshirt2);
        cart.addItem(backPack1);
        System.out.println("Total car value before discounts \t" +cart.totalCartValue());
        couponAll.apply(cart);
        //System.out.println(backPack1.getClass().isInstance(backPack1));
        System.out.println("Total car value after discounts \t" +cart.totalCartValue());
    }

}
```

[image: Sample Input and Output]

Hope this helps.